# Make the linked images show well?

Tags: front-end, image

```
Cell[TextData[{ "(16) ", ButtonBox["[images]",  BaseStyle->"Hyperlink",  ButtonData->{"https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHWby.png", None}]}], "Text"]
```

After click the link, then open one notebook, however it's in bad encoding?

[image]

My `$CharacterEncoding` is `CP936`, I'm not sure whether this is related, I'm on Windows, maybe someone's environment will show the linked image good?

Comment: This occurs because you are opening the PNG file directly in the front end. Try importing it as an image instead.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I encountered with this by accident. So I'm not sure whether this is one feature of Mathematica.
Because sometimes when we add links of web images, then click just comes out the System Internet Explorer.

Comment: I don't know why that happens. If that's what you want, though, you can use `SystemOpen`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. `SystemOpen` is ok, but in this case, I just wanna image show in Mathematica's new open notebook, something like Latex's formula preview or MathML window in SE, I just think it maybe developed by some setting about encoding that makes this action like as expected.  Also something like a button on the image link, and then `Import` and show the image(or image's codes) in one New open Notebook.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you want, but does this help at all? `CellPrint@Cell[
  TextData[{ "(16) ", 
    ButtonBox["[images]", Evaluator -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> "Hyperlink", 
     ButtonFunction -> (Print @ Import @ # &), 
     ButtonData -> "http://i.stack.imgur.com/gHWby.png"]}], "Text"]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, something like that. Maybe my question is not a good, because I create links by `Ctrl+Shift+H`, and then add `[http:links]` and with `[]`(copy carelessly) by mistake, and then I remove those `[]` in CellExpression, they are not the same as that copied without `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are finding a way to open images in a new notebook, so this might be of help:

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nb, 
Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[
          Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHWby.png"]
    ]]]]
```

Comment: Yes, this is one possible way, but I'm more curious to know whether there would be possible to set some options, and make the example I  figured works well.